# scanf issue when reading input from pipe

Tags: c++, c

I am writing a program in C, where I am attempting to create an automated testing program. A process would be spawned whose I/O channels (stdin, stdout and stderr) would be redirected to a "black box testing module". 
Let us assume a simple program involving multiplication of two numbers. In this case, the program to be tested looks as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b, numTc, i = 0; //numTc being the number of test cases
    scanf("%d",&numTc);
    for(;i < numTc; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d%d",&a,&b); //Facing issue here
        printf("%d\n",a*b);
    }
}
```

The black box test module first redirects the I/O channels of this program to a pipe and then uses the `write()` system call to first write the number of test cases followed by the the test cases themselves.

The issue that I am facing is:
The process hangs on the second scanf as marked above. If I construct the entire input buffer and write it to the pipe after appending a "\n", then things are working fine.

However, I want to achieve the functionality one by one.

Following is the logic of the black box module:

1. Read total test cases from database
2. Construct an input buffer that has all the test cases separated by a space and ends with a newline.
3. Write this buffer to stdin of external (process to be tested) process
4. Wait for output from the tested process.

The above is working fine. However, the black box module should be able to write the test cases one by one.

Comment: It's generally better style to write `for (i = 0; i < numTx; i++)` than to do the loop control initialization in the separate declaration.  In C99 (which you must be using since you don't return a value explicitly from `main()`), you could write `for (int i = 0; i < numTc; i++)`.

Comment: Put a space between the two `%d`s in that scanf.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to read two single digit integers that are right next to each other? If so, you might consider using `%1d`.

It would be helpful to have an example of your input.

Comment: Sample input: 2 3 4 5 6 Where 2=>Number of test cases followed by two pairs of numbers. So the output will be 3*4=12 and 5*6=30

Comment: The first `%d` will read until the first character that can't be part of its number (a space, a newline, a minus sign after some digits, etc); the second `%d` will skip leading white space and try to convert what follows into another number.  There's no actual problem with `"%d%d"` if the numbers sent are in fact separated.  If you need to read two single-digit numbers, then you do have to worry about `"%1d%1d"`, but the space is still not mandatory, though it is conventional and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most probably that standard I/O to a pipe behaves differently from standard I/O to a terminal.  It is line buffered by default when writing to a terminal; it is fully buffered when writing to a pipe.  So, your program needs to `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf()` to actually send the data down the pipe.

Strictly, you should be checking the return values from `scanf()` to ensure you are getting what you expect.  If the first `scanf()` does not return 1 or the second does not return 2, you've got problems.

You can debug your problem, perhaps, by opening a log file to see exactly what is being read.  Make sure you flush the output to that log file too.

Comment: I guess flushing wont be a solution here since after entering the for loop, the program is blocked in the scanf call.

Comment: @Cik: maybe, maybe not...if it is the first iteration of the loop, perhaps not, but I'm taking a guess that it is the second iteration that is hanging, and the trouble is that the black box tester is waiting for the answer to the first question before writing the second.  That is, the input will be a `2` (two sums to calculate) followed by `3 4` on a line; the program reads that, computes the answer `12` and does `printf()`; then goes back to wait for the next input, but the tester is waiting to see the `12` before sending the `5 6` for the second calculation.